How do I retract an erroneous duplicate vote in Staging Ground?
Earlier today I reviewed a question in the Staging Ground by voting as duplicate. Shortly after that, I realized that I'd made a mistake and had missed critical context already in the question that made it not actually a duplicate (at least, not of the dupe target I chose).
It was not immediately apparent if or how I could retract the duplicate vote as I can on the main site, and I would hate to have had a part in marking any question as such that is certainly otherwise on-topic and/or salvageable with edits.

"Approve and post on main site" is still enabled, but I personally don't think the question has all the necessary details yet to make it passable for this option & have provided feedback for the original poster to action before I'd consider selecting this option.
"Conditionally approve with minor edits" is also enabled, but I think the edits that I've suggested amount to "major changes", so this isn't an appropriate action, either.
"Require major changes" is enabled, but (as I mentioned above) I've already added a comment outlining the particulars of what information would be necessary to make the question on-topic and answerable on the main site and selected this option.
"Vote as off-topic", too, is enabled, but I think at its core the question is on-topic.
"Vote as duplicate" is disabled, with the (1) indicator reflecting my earlier (erroneous) vote.
"Decline request for re-evaluation" is disabled, as expected, since the OP has not yet submitted their question for re-evaluation.

In short:

Can I retract my duplicate vote on a Staging Ground post, like I can with posts on the main site?
If so, how? (If this is documented anywhere in the reviewer UI, the Help Center or on Meta, I couldn't locate it despite my best efforts.)
If not, is there any particular reason why this doesn't function the same way as it does on the main site?



Can I retract my duplicate vote, like I can on the main site?

No, the Staging Ground does not allow you to retract duplicate votes. As far as I know, this was just never implemented as it's possible to easily move to "Requires Major Changes" or approving whenever you want to.

"Vote as off-topic", too, is enabled, but I think at its core the question is on-topic.

Actually, this wouldn't work. Once you selected "Vote as duplicate" on a question, you can no longer use the "Vote as off-topic" (or vice-versa) option on that post.
What to do
A single duplicate vote doesn't cause that many issues. The main thing to do is ensuring the post is in the appropriate state by using the corresponding option. If the post already is in "Major Changes", just keep it there. If the post is in any other state and should be "Major Changes", use your comments (which you said you have already written) for a "Requires Major Changes" review which moves the question to "Major Changes".
In addition to that, you can write a comment telling the author to disregard the information about the duplicate, for example as a reply to the automated comment that got created in response to your "duplicate" review action. This ensures the author isn't confused about the duplicate message.

Nevermind the above comment. I didn't notice that [...]. Please still [edit] your question according to the changes requested before.

If you don't have an option to use "Major Changes" because the comments were written too long ago, you can also use that comment for the "Requires Major Changes" review option.

Yep, happened to me once... When I realised, I then deleted the automatic Comment posted on my behalf en re-posted it with an "heavy" edit (meant for the Asker, but also for other Reviewers) mentioning I had made a mistake about that specific Dupe-Target.

Thanks. I'd still posit this is a slightly rough edge in the UI/UX - a mistaken, irrevocable vote like mine pushes the post 50% of the way to being formally marked as a duplicate; if it does end up that another reviewer votes in the same way (for whatever reason) the messaging above the fold would be pretty confusing & contradictory to what I'd be writing in the comments. I acknowledge that this is the definition of edge case, so I get why it's not really a priority to implement. I was really more curious if I was just missing the option to retract said vote.

"Actually, this wouldn't work. Once you selected "Vote as duplicate" on a question, you can no longer use the "Vote as off-topic" (or vice-versa) option on that post." Assuming this is true, this is probably a UI bug in SG. Definitely showing on my end as a selectable option after having gone back and requesting major changes, but I'm not keen to try and actually vote and mess things up more.

Regarding your first comment: I agree with this being a "slightly rough edge" but even if it is wrongly marked as a duplicate, you can easily change it using a different review operation (e.g. "Major Changes"). For your second comment, I would also like being able to use the duplicate option multiple times on the same post (see the link in my answer) but I wouldn't consider it a bug (except the part about it being shown as enabled) as the main site does the same thing where you can't vote to close a question multiple times.
